# Access permissions to file system objects in Windows via R

Tags: windows, r, filesystems, file-permissions

It seems that sometimes when accessing files in Windows, it takes time to give a success/failure answer, but R scripts don't wait and assume a failure.

To understand what I mean, consider the following lines:

```
is.path=function(path){
    path=sub("/$", "", path)
    file.exists(path)
}
delete=function(x){
    unlink(x,recursive=TRUE)
    if(is.path(x)) stop("\nUnable to access\n", x)
}

delete("foo")
```

After deleting the FS object we check the action succeeded. If `foo` is absolutely free, it works like a charm. Consider the situation in which `foo` is a folder opened as an Explorer window. The deletion will succeed also causing the window to close or point to the parent window.

This negotiation is not perceptible to us users, but R does not wait and triggers the `stop`.

One very simple way fix is to add a delay after the `unlink`, e.g. `Sys.sleep(1)`. Obviously if I set a short delay it will not work for all cases, while a long one will be inefficient for the standard more frequent cases.

Can you help me to find a clever solution?

Comment: `unlink` will not return until it gets a status. Now, quite possibly Windows is sloppy enough that it doesn't do a proper "refresh" and thus thinks the file is still there so far as its response to `file.exists` goes.  I rather doubt that a time delay will work.  You'll need the equivalent of a "refresh" call. Maybe try `file.test` or `file.access` to see if they force a proper Windows status refresh.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: `unlink` is probably implemented using `RemoveDirectory` which will (under certain circumstances, as documented) return success once the removal of the directory has been approved but before it actually occurs.

Comment: There's a well-known but slightly different issue where removing a directory tree will sometimes arbitrarily fail; in that case, removing the tree twice always seems to work.  I suggest you try issuing the `unlink` twice in a row and see whether the problem still occurs.

Comment: Failing that, the only sensible option is probably a short delay in a loop.  Exit the loop once `is.path(x)` returns false, or after the total delay exceeds a suitably chosen timeout value.

Comment: Only `Sys.sleep` works for me (and I assume for everyone else)

Answer (score 0):

My best attempt is only this sort of clever sleep,  which triggers only when necessary to avoid unnecessary delays.

```
is.path=function(path){
    path=sub("/$", "", path)
    file.exists(path)
}
delete=function(x){
    unlink(x,recursive=TRUE)
    if(is.path(x)) {
        Sys.sleep(1.5)
        if(is.path(x)) stop("\nUnable to access\n", x)
    }
}
```